# Automatically recolor cell in table pulled from AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I'm a bit stumped as to how to go about this: what happens, is that I have a function in AJAX printing out text from a php file every 5 seconds, as below:

```
function loadJSON() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'dataPull.php?buster='+Math.random(),
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        setTimeout('loadJSON()',5000);
    },
    success: function (txtInfo) {

        $("#pulltxtdata").text(txtInfo.details.txt.info);
        $("#pulltxtdata2").text(txtInfo.details.txt.info2);
        $("#pulltxtdata3").text(txtInfo.details.txt.info3);

        setTimeout('loadJSON()',5000);
    }
});
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve in the HTML with `<td id="pulltxtdata"></td>` is to recolor the background of the cell each time the value of `pulltxtdata` hits a certain threshold (i.e. red cell background if it goes above 10). Is this something I can include in the JSON/AJAX function or do I somehow need to pull the value of `pulltxtdata` after it computes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding your text, check the value inside `pulltxtdata`:

```
 function loadJSON() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'dataPull.php?buster=' + Math.random(),
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      setTimeout('loadJSON()', 5000);
    },
    success: function(txtInfo) {

      $("#pulltxtdata").text(txtInfo.details.txt.info);
      $("#pulltxtdata2").text(txtInfo.details.txt.info2);
      $("#pulltxtdata3").text(txtInfo.details.txt.info3);

      var pullTxtData = $('#pulltxtdata');

      if (parseInt(pullTxtData.text()) >= 10)
          pullTxtData.css('background-color', 'red');
      });

      setTimeout('loadJSON()', 5000);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: That did the trick (once i removed the extra returns after the css call), thank you! Only question I have left is if it's possible to do multiple thresholds (i.e. if it hits 10 its yellow, above 20 it goes red, etc).

Thanks so much!

Comment: Sure, you can duplicate that if statement, and replace `>= 10` with `>= 20`, and `('background-color', 'red');` with `('background-color', 'yellow')` or whatever color you like. This works for a small number of thresholds (e.g. 5-6 max), but if you'd like something more complex, let me know, you might want to do something more automated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to look at the data being pulled and make a determination of value.  Then you could do something like this:

```
var value = ProperlyConvertToSomeNumber( txtInfo.details.txt.info ) ;

$("#pulltxtdata").text(txtInfo.details.txt.info);
$("#pulltxtdata").css( "background-color",
                       SomeFunctionThatReturnsAColorStringBasedOnValue( value ) );
```